# Central Location for app-generated Images on Android?

Tags: android, image, photo

My app will generate an image at the request of the user. While I know I can write that to the SD Card directly, I'd like to generate the image and put it some place more easily accessible to the user. For example, on iOS I can drop the image in their Photos app. It allows me to do whatever I need to do with the image, but also allows them easy access to it later on.

I've found an Android class called MediaStore.Images.Media (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html) but the javadocs on it are essentially empty. Does anyone know what the MediaStore classes are for?

Is there a better, more accessible, option for storing app-generated images than just writing them to my app's directory on the SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` with the `DIRECTORY_PICTURES` to get the standard location (Android 2.2 and above). It will be on the SD card (external storage) on most(all?) devices.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)